# google sheet App script string length function typeerror

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
  function myFunction(input_data) 
   {
   const myJSON = JSON.stringify(input_data);                                                                      
   const myJSON1 = JSON.parse(myJSON);
   const data = myJSON1["data"];
   const input = JSON.stringify(myJSON1.data);
   var result="";
   //return typeof input;
   for(var i=1;i<input.length-1;i++){
         //Logger.log(input[i]);
         result += input[i];
    }
    Logger.log(result);
    const obj_result = JSON.parse(result);
    const code_status = obj_result.code;
    Logger.log(code_status);
    result_details= JSON.stringify(obj_result.details);
    obj_result_details = JSON.parse(result_details);
    Logger.log(obj_result_details.id);
    return obj_result_details.id;
    }

 input_data = {"data":[{"code":"SUCCESS","details":{"Modified_Time":"2022-08- 
12T18:30:42+05:30","Modified_By":{"name":"",
"id":"8"},"Created_Time":"2022-08- 
12T18:30:42+05:30","id":"87956000","Created_By":{"name":"dev" 
,"id":"8"}},"message":"record added","status":"success"}]};
Logger.log(myFunction(input_data));
```

> Error: TypeError: cann't read property length at line no 9.

(this error I am getting in sheet but not in script editor).

Comment: Why are `stringify`ing after getting `data`?

Comment: The code looks extremely weird. It would be easier if you just tell what you're trying to do with this function? To get a list of IDs?

Answer (score 0):

As a guess. If you meant to get an array of IDs from the `input_data` it can be done this way:

```js
var input_data = {
  data: [
    {
      code: "SUCCESS",
      details: {
        Modified_Time: "2022-08-12T18:30:42+05:30",
        Modified_By: { name: "", id: "8" },
        Created_Time: "2022-08-12T18:30:42+05:30",
        id: "87956000",
        Created_By: { name: "dev", id: "8" },
      },
      message: "record added",
      status: "success",
    },
  ],
};

function myFunction(input_data) {
  return input_data.data.map(x => x.details.id);
}

console.log(myFunction(input_data)); // output: [ '87956000' ]
```